# Simple Prolog program - Unsure about results

Tags: prolog

Completely new to Prolog (SWI-Prolog in this case) so apologies for this very basic question. I have a simple program below.

```
loves(vincent,mia).
loves(marsellus,mia). 
loves(pumpkin,honey_bunny).
loves(honey_bunny,pumpkin).

jealous(X, Y):- loves(X,Z), loves(Y,Z).
```

I'm a little confused as to the results of the following query:

```
?- jealous(vincent, X).
X = vincent ;
X = marsellus.
```

Perhaps I'm just not accustomed to the unification process of Prolog, but shouldn't the answer just be marsellus? Why is vincent included here as a valid result?

Also, as a followup question: Am I correct in that in order to get a result of all the 'jealous' people, I would write a query such as jealous(X, Y). ?

If so, can someone explain the following result of said query?

```
?- jealous(X, Y).
X = Y, Y = vincent ;
X = vincent,
Y = marsellus ;
X = marsellus,
Y = vincent ;
X = Y, Y = marsellus ;
X = Y, Y = pumpkin ;
X = Y, Y = honey_bunny.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Source: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/kb.pl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question, I can see how the output makes sense.

You're asking for a list of people that love the same person that Vincent loves.

Since both Vincent and Marsellus love Mia, the list is `{Vincent, Marsellus}`, as you are getting.

I'm not sure of the syntax for Prolog but you'd want something like:

```
jealous(X, Y):- loves(X,Z), loves(Y,Z), X \== Y.
```

to remove those cases where X and Y refer to the same person, using whatever symbol in Prolog meaning "not equal to" if it's not `\==`.

It's a little hard to be jealous of *yourself* unless you're suffering from some sort of split-personality disorder and, if you are, you could argue it's *not* yourself you're actually jealous of, `self` becoming a rather fluid concept in those circumstances.

---

The second question output also makes sense, after a bit of thought, and is related to the same problem as described above. Looking at the output slightly reformatted:

```
X = Y,         Y = vincent ;
X = vincent,   Y = marsellus ;
X = marsellus, Y = vincent ;
X = Y,         Y = marsellus ;
X = Y,         Y = pumpkin ;
X = Y,         Y = honey_bunny.
```

These are the jealousy ouputs, with the `X = Y` meaning exactly that, `X` and `Y` are the same, with `Y` being specified as the second item on each line. It can be rewritten as:

```
X = vincent,     Y = vincent ;
X = vincent,     Y = marsellus ;
X = marsellus,   Y = vincent ;
X = marsellus,   Y = marsellus ;
X = pumpkin,     Y = pumpkin ;
X = honey_bunny, Y = honey_bunny.
```

In other words, similar to the first question, everyone is jealous of *themselves,* as well as any other people who may love a given target.

I suspect that, if you modify the jealousy detector as suggested, all that self-loathing may just disappear, and the world will be a happier place.

Well, other than for Vincent and Marsellus, who obviously still dislike each other, and who are both suffering from unrequited love. The world can sometimes be such a harsh place :-)

Comment: Thanks. You look to be correct. I guess I have to explicitly state that X and Y cannot be the same. I thought this would be inferred by the rule I wrote, but I guess not!

Comment: Also, the correct way to write it in SWI-Prolog would be X \== Y (feel free to edit that into your answer above for others).

Comment: @Decoy, thanks for that, I've added it in. I also think I nutted out the second question, it's caused by the same issue. See the updated answer.

Comment: Use rather [tag:prolog-dif] instead.